# ASP.NET Core MVC : First ViewModel to create view showing Activity and linked identities

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

I'm attempting to create a ViewModel which will combine the data in 2 Models to create a view which provides Activity details and a table providing information of identities which are lnked to that activity.

Here are the Models:

ActivityItem

```
namespace MISDataRepo.Models
{
    [Table("Activity",Schema = "test")]
    public partial class ActivityItem
    {
        public ActivityItem()
        {
            ActivityIdentifier = new HashSet<ActivityIdentifier>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Activity Name is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Type")]
        public int ActivityTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Date is required!")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Created")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Modified")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DatetModified { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The PID of the User creating the Activity must be entered")]
        [Display(Name = "Created By (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Co-Ordinator (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? PC { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Live { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }

        //public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ActivityIdentifier> ActivityIdentifier { get; set; }

        
    }
}
```

ActivityIdentifier

```
namespace MISDataRepo.Models
{
    [Table("ActivityIdentifier", Schema = "test")]
    public partial class ActivityIdentifier
    {

        

        [Key]
        public int ActivityIdentifierId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Activity Identifier is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Identifier Value")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        public string IdentifierValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int IdentifierTypeId { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Live { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityItem ActivityItem { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentifierType IdentifierType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm looking for a view that shows the following

**Activity Details**

```
Activity Name:  ABC
Date Created: 01/01/2022
Date Modified: 
Creade By (Employee ID): 1234567
Project CoOrdinator: 1234567
```

**Identifiers**

```
| Id Type | Identifier| Live (chkbox)|
|:------- |:---------:| ------------:|
| foo     | 12345     |      x       |
| bar     | 67890     |      x       |
```

Unfortunately i don't have any code to provide examples of what I've tried as I've returned the app to an earlier saved version having decided to give up at one point, but this is something I want to do as part of learning MVC.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as below in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var activityIitemvm = await _context.ActivityItem.Include(x => x.ActivityIdentifier).ThenInclude(y=>y.IdentifierType).Where(x=>x.ActivityItemId==id)
                                                             .Select(x => new ActivityItemViewModel()
                                                             {
                                                                 ActivityIdentifier=x.ActivityIdentifier.Select(y=>new ActivityIdentifierVM
                                                                 {
                                                                     Id=y.ActivityIdentifierId,
                                                                     Type=y.IdentifierType.TypeName,
                                                                     IdentifierId=y.IdentifierType.Id,
                                                                     Live=y.Live
                                                                 }).ToList(),
                                                                 ActivityName = x.ActivityName,
                                                                 CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                                                                 DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
                                                                 DatetModified = x.DatetModified

                                                             }).FirstAsync();
           

            if (activityIitemvm == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            

            return View(activityIitemvm);
        }
```

Models:

```
public ActivityItem()
        {
            ActivityIdentifier = new HashSet<ActivityIdentifier>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Activity Name is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Type")]
        public int ActivityTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Date is required!")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Created")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Modified")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DatetModified { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The PID of the User creating the Activity must be entered")]
        [Display(Name = "Created By (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Co-Ordinator (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? PC { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Live { get; set; }

       

        //public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ActivityIdentifier> ActivityIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ActivityIdentifier
    {
        [Key]
        public int ActivityIdentifierId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Activity Identifier is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Identifier Value")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        public string IdentifierValue { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int IdentifierTypeId { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Live { get; set; }
        public virtual ActivityItem ActivityItem { get; set; }

        public virtual IdentifierType IdentifierType { get; set; }

    }

    public class IdentifierType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityItemViewModel
    {   
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatetModified { get; set; }
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ActivityIdentifierVM> ActivityIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityIdentifierVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int IdentifierId { get; set; }

        public bool Live { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <h4>ActivityIdentifier</h4>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ActivityName
            </th>
            <th>
                CreatedBy
            </th>
            <th>
                DateCreated
            </th>
            <th>
                DatetModified
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.ActivityName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.CreatedBy
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.DateCreated
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.DatetModified
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ActivityIdentifier
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                IdentifierId
            </th>
            <th>
                Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Live
            </th>            
        </tr>
        @foreach (var ActivityIdentifier in Model.ActivityIdentifier)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @ActivityIdentifier.Id
        </td>
        <td>
            @ActivityIdentifier.IdentifierId
        </td>
        <td>
            @ActivityIdentifier.Type
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model=> ActivityIdentifier.Live)
        </td>
    </tr>

        }
    </table>
        
       
</div>
```

Tried with the uri:`https://localhost:44385/ActivityIdentifiers/Details/1`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You.  This works and provides me not only with an understanding but enough to create the View I was looking for.